# Configuring OpenVPN to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn

I am trying to configure OpenVPN to my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance.  I have opened up both TCP and UDP ports on both the load balancer and the VPC instance.  I can connect if I open my putty session to the server and set a SSH tunnel on port 1194, and then connect OpenVPN on localhost 1194, but I am trying to figure out how to set my DNS entry so that I can just connect through the VPN using UDP without setting a SSH tunnel.  Any advice?  I have tried so many combinations and read everything I can find...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally worked it out.  The cname has to match the actual address of the vpc directly, it cannot go through the load balancer and the aname matches the IP of the OpenVPN.